# JQuery-Ajax second function executing before first function

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have two dropdowns one for country and another for states. 2nd dropdown loads after firt one. I have two functions such as 
LoadCountry() and LoadStates(),where LoadState fire off after LoadCountry.

My issue is, getting 0 or null when i try to get the value of drpCountry as

**var CId = $("#" + '<%=drpCountry.ClientID%>').val()**;.

The issue is only happening at the the time of page load. When i change values of drpCountry the data load 
correctily in the drpState. Facing same issue in the other webpages also which have 4 to 5 dropdowns. But when i change the execution speed by setting setTimeout its woks
fine.

I can strongly say that the data is loading correclty. 
 a,I checked it in the console.
 b,when i change dropdown data loading to drpState Correctly

Why LoadState() executes before LoadCountry() executes completly ?

```
    $(function() {
    LoadCountry();
    LoadState();
    /* when set timeout LoadState works fine */
    //setTimeout(function () {
    //LoadState();
    //}, 200);

    /* Changed Timeout when upload to server */
    //setTimeout(function () {
    //LoadState();
    //}, 300);

    $("#<%=drpCountry.ClientID%>").change(function() {
        LoadState();
    })
});

function LoadCountry() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        url: 'country.aspx/Loadcountry',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.d.length > 0) {
                $("#<%=drpCountry.ClientID%>").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    var Value = data.d[i];
                    var Id = Value.split('/')[0];
                    var Name = Value.split('/')[1];
                    $("#<%=drpCountry.ClientID%>").append($('<option>', {
                        value: Id,
                        text: Name
                    }));
                }
            } else {
                $("#<%=drpCountry.ClientID%>").empty();
                $("#<%=drpCountry.ClientID%>").append($('<option>', {
                    value: "0",
                    text: "--Select--"
                }));
            }
        }
    });
}

function LoadState() {
    var CId = $("#" + '<%=drpCountry.ClientID%>').val();
    alert(CId); //Getting Zero as Cid but have values
    $("#<%=drpState.ClientID%>").append($('<option>', {
        value: "0",
        text: "--Loading--"
    }));
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        url: 'country.aspx/LoadState',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{'CId':'" + CId + "'}",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.d.length > 0) {
                $("#<%=drpState.ClientID%>").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    var Value = data.d[i];
                    var Id = Value.split('/')[0];
                    var Name = Value.split('/')[1];
                    $("#<%=drpState.ClientID%>").append($('<option>', {
                        value: Id,
                        text: Name
                    }));
                }
            } else {
                $("#<%=drpState.ClientID%>").empty();
                $("#<%=drpState.ClientID%>").append($('<option>', {
                    value: "0",
                    text: "--Select--"
                }));
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try calling `LoadState` function inside ajax success and also pass country id as an argument in `LoadState`function

Comment: @Lepanto thanks for the suggestion.i will try..

Comment: i put loadState() inside ajax success and its works fine... thank you for ur support..

Answer (score 0):

I tried some steps and seems below code will work,

```
var stateVar = true;

function loadState(){
  // some code
}

function loadCountry(){
  $.ajax({
    ...
    ...
    success:function(res){
      if(stateVar){ loadState(); stateVar = false; }
    }
  })
}

$(function() {
    LoadCountry();
    $("#<%=drpCountry.ClientID%>").change(function() {
        LoadState();
    })
});
```

Comment: i put loadState() inside ajax success and its works fine... thank you for ur support..